# Gevent queue high CPU usage

Tags: python, queue, gevent

Why this code permanently uses 95% of CPU? Producer doesn't sending any request, but cpu is hot. How to lower cpu usage without adding explicit non-zero sleep timeout in consumer greenlet?

```
from gevent import queue
from gevent import sleep
from gevent import Greenlet

def cons(q):
    while True:
        try:
            data = q.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            sleep(0)
            continue
        print data

def prod(q):
    while True:
        #q.put_nowait('hello')
        sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    q = queue.Queue()
    cons1 = Greenlet.spawn(cons, q)
    prod1 = Greenlet.spawn(prod, q)
    cons1.join()
    prod1.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 8, use get() instead of get_nowait()

```
data = q.get()
```

Super simple, now your consumer will block while waiting for more work.

Comment: It's good but it's bad solution if I have more than one queue(control and data channels, for example). I have simply added sleep(0.00001) as workaround - CPU load 3% instead of 96.

Comment: @echo12345 Don't use `sleep`! The `get` method has a `timeout` parameter: `q.get(timeout=0.001)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're not supposed to use get_nowait() or timeout parameters.  If you read more than one queue, then just make more than one greenlet.  Unlike threads, greenlets are cheap to create and teardown (in possibly large numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Best solution of all recommended:
  Use queue.get blocking call inside separate greenlets for each queue.

Next part of code polls two gevent.queue queues + zmq.green socket inside greenlets inside greenlet =)
CPU Load is near zero!

```
def _zmq_poll(self):
    while True:
        sockets = super(Core, self)._zmq_poll()
        if sockets:
            if sockets.get(self.z_ctr) == zmq.POLLIN:
                self.ctr_process()

def ctr_process(self):
    self.send_log('new CTR: %s')

def req_process(self):
    while True:
        req = self.q_req_core.get()
        self.send_log('new req: %s' % req)
        self.q_core_wrk.put(req)

def wrk_process(self):
    while True:
        wrk_result = self.q_wrk_core.get()
        self.send_log('new result: %s' % wrk_result)
        self.q_core_res.put(wrk_result)
        self.test_wrk_result(wrk_result)

def _run(self):
    self.slaves_start()
    req_process = Greenlet(self.req_process)
    wrk_process = Greenlet(self.wrk_process)
    zmq_poll = Greenlet(self._zmq_poll)
    req_process.start()
    wrk_process.start()
    zmq_poll.start()
    zmq_poll.join()
    req_process.join()
    wrk_process.join()
    self._cleanup()
```

Thanks for advices!